# stdint for C++98 (gcc/clang)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++98

Why do GCC/clang complain about including `cstdint` but not about `stdint.h` when compiling for C++98?

Compiling with `-std=c++98 -x c++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` [outputs](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmpAAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMXF2mA6pQgRMxATpPn5ctpj2uQxVNQT5YZHRsbbVtfWZTQqDXcE9RX1mAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuY/iCAHQIB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHyMfBBJfXNxzztJwArLw/BwtKRUJw3NZrLsFItlk8NjxSARND95gBrCSSU4ATjMOI0Zn%2BOMkZjMki4AA5CfpOJIgaiwZxeAoQBpkaj5nBYDBECBFgR4l4CORKGgWPE6NFQqxVqpKQA2AC0Csku22hmAuy4CtOGj1vEw%2BCIxDw6D0/EEIjE7CkMkEihU6hBOj0AHdiEx4pzaRxAaRgaDwRwAPLCoUEXaoKi7eXK1XqgxGbW6/UaXYQDwSqXEfZmdZcWa8FEurlIcWS%2BhkCgQCs5lBJ4A6jTsrAANzwKwAanhMG6Q/FGJwkTRaARoqyIBFGRFgjUAJ7D3iz5jEechiLacolpHitiCEMMWiL7i8LARLzANxiWis0%2BkLAsTXiF0PvDEbd4NuYO%2BgzCqcphVWJF3haRlaDwCJPTXDwsCXZFTRYJd5ioAxgAUHs%2BwHId70tYRRHEO08MdNRGV0JpGxQKFLH0SDWVgZg2BATACFoUhvxiAhiC8Bh0VmeZUHiNo7yVY4DgAEVMSxrBxSldiVVR1Woix5IAdRvNT/y4ph5MHdBDEcZBeFQDjTSweiIHmMoKmcCBXGGRpSECSZCmKLIkhSAQHPcnJUm6Vy%2BlGFpPwEDohk8Bo9GstowomApehiUZxm8pLOn8hKJCsuEVky31/UDYzOFjRUVTVDVkx1PU9QzXBCBIPMCyLDlS3mBBMCYLAYks0hMXWbFKUkAB2BV/g0f4uHWHFRo0SlfXpUgkNGgNGWDFk2WarQuV5CAkAFCNRVrVBsyrGUmI4ONSt2YBkGQbV1lOMxDWNEgzQtWRrUI6RiKUUjX10OIPS9H0/j9BlX2DMNBWFKMYwuhNrtuiaHozLNK2iBq5mLH0dpQI60erMU8frJt1jidtO0wTD%2B0HYERzocdiEnadXxXBd4NZtcNy3Bx4L3RgCEPY9GXPS9r1oW94MfZ9VlBfAPwqb9f0NADkCA%2BDQJB0EIKghdYJl4tEOQvg0Iw3tqZwkd3oI20vtkEjnVBf79E1KjpJo7WLIEoTUhEsT1kk5TZPkxSpKsSw1I0pVVK0z1dKNAzO2M0yzR/eArOCmy/Dshh3AikYnJz9LpkShIPLaFLS98vIXIyoLWkqZK88c6KG7Smvi6ixuMmb8Yi7cwsFiWHKB5B/KVqKuG1QRu7kYgWqTQawssZa0g2o6vpupB%2BbFvZAqmQ4Nb2RLTaMRASl/j1QaNBxQbJDGwbBv%2BSkuBxX11jBoNmQ2tFfUehaJBbMtcGX9j4/w4skZwkggA%3D%3D) for `#include <cstdint>`:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard.

According to the C++98 standard none of the headers are defined.

Comment: I guess the GCC/glibc developers are just being pragmatic. The header didn't exist before C99/C++11 and if someone includes it before that, then the program behavior isn't specified anyway. So there is no conformance issue. For the `<cstdint>` variant, the implentation is supposed to introduce the declaration to `std::` via a `using` declaration if the type is already declared in the global namespace scope. Since `using` is a C++11 feature, the header can't work in previous C++ modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## GCC

The `#include` directive is executed by the GNU C preprocessor (CPP) for C *and* C++ sources. The standard system directories for header files, searched at by default by CPP, contain the headers for the C Standard Library. For C++ additional directories are used for the search first. Thus even for C++ source the C Standard Library headers are available by default. The header `stdint.h` found is thus not the compatibility header available since C++11. But instead the C Standard Library header available since C99.

I deduced this from [an old version of the GNU CPP documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Search-Path.html):

> GCC looks in several different places for headers. [...] For C++ programs, it will also look in [...], first.

See also the GNU CPP options [`-nostdinc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#index-nostdinc) and [`-nostdinc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#index-nostdinc_002b_002b).

⚠ I assume this behavior is not backed by the C++ Standard.

Comment: GCC will find its own wrapper for `stdint.h` regardless of the `-std` flag or even whether C or C++ is used. See https://godbolt.org/z/o5EeM7cYe. They could have decided to fail this inclusion depending on the C/C++ mode, but didn't. It also works in C89 mode with `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 0):

The **C++** standard only documents headers that are part of **C++** standard library. One of such headers, since C++11, is `cstdint`. If you include this header in C++03 or C++98 mode, the compiler generates a warning that this header is not part of the C++ standard version you selected.

The `stdint.h` header is part of the **C** standard library and is not covered by **C++** standard (other than as a reference to the C standard). This header is also described in a number of other standards, such as [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html). C++ compilers allow including C standard library headers, as well as system headers, which is why including `stdint.h` works, although the types defined by that header are not placed in `namespace std`. In fact, it is often (but not necessarily) the case that C++ standard headers are implemented using C standard headers internally. Nevertheless, the C++ standard does not cover those headers, and indeed those headers don't depend on the C++ version you choose. Hence the compiler does not complain when you include those headers, even if in an older C++ version.

Comment: This is not true. `stdint.h` and other headers are covered in the C++ standard in [support.c.headers.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.c.headers.general).

Comment: @JanSchultke The title and the first paragraph of that section confirms what I'm saying - "C headers". The C++ standard simply acknowledges there is C standard library and that it is available to C++ programs. It does not define contents of those headers, other than referring to the C standard.

Comment: Note that `stdint.h` is not mentioned in the old *C++98* standard.

Comment: @user5534993 It doesn't need to be. The point my answer makes is that there are headers that are not covered by the C++ standard. A C++ compiler doesn't need to issue warnings about those headers.

Comment: I understand and agree with your answer @AndreySemashev. ✔

Comment: I was just confused that the compilers used C99 headers although I explicitly specified C++98.  It is not illegal. But I did not expect this as default behavior.

Comment: @AndreySemashev the C++ standard acknowledges the existence, and even the contents (in some cases) of C headers. It did that for some headers all the way back in C++98. The fact that it doesn't for `stdint.h`/`cstdint` is because that's a C99 header and thus C++98 predates it. However, it's safe to assume that the same sort of interoperability for C99 headers should be possible before C++11 too.

Comment: @AndreySemashev The C++ versions of the C standard library headers are not equivalent to the C versions. They are defined by C++, just largely by reference to their C contents. For example `<math.h>` is guaranteed to contain overloads in C++ that couldn't exist in C.